# Бесконечный ряд и ошибка в коде

Tags: c, ряды

Дали задание: найти сумму бесконечного ряда с заданной точностью с использованием рекуррентной формулы. Ручками все нашёл и приступил к написанию кода, только вот ничего в итоге не получилось. Сам ищу ошибку, да найти не могу. Если нужен будет сам ряд или точность, а может мои вычисления - жду комментариев, так как сам не исключаю варианта того, что ошибкой может быть какой-нибудь пустяк.

```
{
    const double EPS = 1.0e-6;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    double x, sum=0.5,r;
    int i;
    scanf_s("%lf", &x);
        x = 0.5;
        i = 0;
        while (fabs(sum >= EPS)) {
            sum += x;
            i++;
            x *= (((-2 * 2) * (x * x))) / ((2 * i) * (2 * i - 1));
        }
        printf("summa ryada: %lf", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Заранее всем кто помог получает по котёнку бесплатно!

Это мои вычисления:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это сам бесконечный ряд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция для проверки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: scanf_s("%lf", &x);
        x = 0.5; - Считали X , а потом его изменили

Comment: Ещё с этим надо что-то делать: fabs(sum >= EPS)

Comment: *Если нужен будет сам ряд или точность, а может мои вычисления* — на будущее: они **всегда** нужны, чтобы хотя бы вопрос не закрыли с формулировкой "*Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.*"

Comment: Что вы хотели сказать этим: `while (fabs(sum >= EPS)) {` ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy цикл, чтобы сумма моего ряда не превышала заданной точности.. или что-то не так?..

Comment: @Виктор Ой, и вправду, спасибо большое, чего-то я этого не заметил.. А насчёт цикла, что с ним не так? Я его добавил, чтобы сумма моего ряда не превышала заданную точность

Comment: Что-то не так. `fabs` вычисляется от логической величины (чего быть не должно), `while` вместо логической величины получает число (чего тоже быть не должно).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отрадно видеть, что шаги решения проработаны, члены ряды вычисляются, как положено.

Дефекты в реализации. Вы портите `x`, а ведь переменную `r` для очередного слагаемого подготовили, и не разобрались, как оценивать точность - с `EPS` нужно сравнивать абсолютное значение очередного члена ряда:

```
 double x, sum=0.5,r;
 int i;
 scanf_s("%lf", &x);
 r = 0.5;
 i = 0;
        while (fabs(r) >= EPS) {
            sum += r;
            i++;
            r *= (((-2 * 2) * (x * x))) / ((2 * i) * (2 * i - 1));
        }
```